# I can't scroll the window on android, ios

Tags: jquery, scroll, iscroll

i'm using iScroll for my mobile chat, version for ios or android.

But i can't scroll the window, indeed it's like blocked, i can't do anything with the screen.

I tried with my iphone but i can't do anything, i read some documentation about that but idon't know whuch part i have to make the modification.

See below my code, thanks if you have any idea.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
var myScroll;
var showkey =true;
function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#contenu', { 
    tap:true,
    desktopCompatibility: true,
    onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
                var nodeType = e.explicitOriginalTarget ? e.explicitOriginalTarget.nodeName.toLowerCase():(e.target ? e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase():'');

                if(nodeType !='select' && nodeType !='option' && nodeType !='input' && nodeType!='textarea' && !showkey) {
                     e.preventDefault();    //prevents showing keyboard - scrolling
                }//otherwise, show keyboard, do default
                if(!showkey) showkey = true;
            },       
    });
    $('a, input, #sendmsg, .ml_tabs').on('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(iScrollLoad, 200); }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea guys ? i use Iscroll 5

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a jsfiddle.

Just for notice: By adding this line of code `$('a, input, #sendmsg, .ml_tabs').on('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });`

You're gonna prevent anything to happen especially when trying you start your touchmove event on an `<a>`Tag or an `<input>` and so on.

What you should know is, that iScroll does'nt like the `overflow` attribute in CSS. It's a good thing, to set `overflow: hidden !important;` to the container, you wanna scroll.

When initializnig iScroll use `preventDefault: false //do not prevent a possible click - we'll take care of it`

`myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
            preventDefault: false
        });`